# Installation Error (Ubuntu partitioning on disk shared with Windows 10)

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation, dual-boot

I'm installing the Ubuntu along with Windows 10 and I already separated the free space on the Windows machine and started the Ubuntu installation. All went successfully but  installation type "free space" main options are disabled, even right click is not showing add option to separate the swap. System details: 750 GB hard drive, 6 GB RAM.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what the question is. I am assuming when you say "free space" you are talking about that partition that Ubuntus partitioner is marking "unusable", meaning, you can not use it. I have rarely seen that in my installations of linux. It is usally marked someting else. Why do you have so many primary ntfs partitions? I think the installer might think you are at the maximum number of ntfs partitions. I would use windows to combine some, then a gparted boot media to create a new partition for ubuntu. (or perhaps just use gparted to make a new partition, or see why that one is unusable.)

Comment: Could you please let me know how to use gparted boot media.

Comment: Basically, download, burn to media, boot, choose the disc, modify the partitions to your liking, hit apply, wait, click reboot twice, remove media. To be more specific [read the docs](https://gparted.org/help.php)

Comment: Welcome,  on the MBR partition table,  the max number of the primary partition is fixed to 4.

Comment: @GAD3R Please do not post answers as comments.  **;-)** (If you post an answer and ping me, I'll come back and upvote)

Answer (score 2):

On the MBR partition table, the maximum number of the primary partition is limited to 4.

To install Ubuntu you should create an extended partition:

1. Back up your data
2. Remove a primary partition
3. Create an extended partition to set your root and swap partition.
4. Restore the partition you removed in step 2 inside the extended partition

   [Help-Ubuntu: How to Partition/Extended Partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/ExtendedPartition)

Comment: An edit and an upvote!